# The best way to get years between two dates in R

Tags: r

I'd like to calculate a difference between two dates in years with decimal values. Let's say we have "1978-08-25" and "2014-02-05" (%Y-%m-%d). How can I calculate the difference between these two dates in years with decimal values (ie. not just 35 years, but 35.95...years)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: check out the `lubridate` package

Comment: somewhat close: `as.integer(as.Date("2014-02-05") - as.Date("1978-08-25")) / 365.25`

Comment: `0.95` years is not a well defined quantity of time.

Answer (score 3):

You could check out the [`zoo`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) package.

```
x = as.yearmon("2014-02-05")
y = as.yearmon("1978-08-25")

x - y
[1] 35.5
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth noting that this really can't be answered definitively (as @hadley alluded to). Even the base `difftime` function in R only allows the options of:

```
...units = c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks"))
```

No months, no years, because they are not definite values. Having said that, you can closely approximate something sensible using @flodel's method in the comments.