# How to calculate the sequential date diff in a dataframe and make it as another column for further analysis?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

**Please before make it as duplicate read carefully my question!**

I am new in `R` and I am trying to figure it out how to calculate the **sequential** `date difference` from one row/variable compare to the next row/variable in based on `weeks` and create another field/column for making a graph accordingly.

There are couple of answer here [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454476/get-the-difference-between-dates-in-terms-of-weeks-months-quarters-and-years/29785779#29785779) , [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591382/the-best-way-to-get-years-between-two-dates-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) , [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583759/how-to-calculate-month-difference-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)  but none specifically talk about making difference in one column sequentially between `rows` lets say from `top to bottom`.

Below is the example and the expected results:

```
Date        Var1 
2/6/2017    493
2/20/2017   558
3/6/2017    595
3/20/2017   636
4/6/2017    697
4/20/2017   566
5/5/2017    234
```

**Expected**

```
Date    Var1    week
2/6/2017    493 0
2/20/2017   558 2
3/6/2017    595 4
3/20/2017   636 6
4/6/2017    697 8
4/20/2017   566 10
5/6/2017    234 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a similar approach to that in your first linked answer by saving the `difftime` result as a new column in your data frame.

```
# Set up data
df <- read.table(text = "Date        Var1 
                 2/6/2017    493
                 2/20/2017   558
                 3/6/2017    595
                 3/20/2017   636
                 4/6/2017    697
                 4/20/2017   566
                 5/5/2017    234", header = T)
df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format = "%m/%d/%Y")

# Create exact week variable
df$week <- difftime(df$Date, first(df$Date), units = "weeks")

# Create rounded week variable
df$week2 <- floor(difftime(df$Date, first(df$Date), units = "weeks"))

df                   
# Date        Var1 week            week2
# 2017-02-06  493  0.000000 weeks  0 weeks
# 2017-02-20  558  2.000000 weeks  2 weeks
# 2017-03-06  595  4.000000 weeks  4 weeks
# 2017-03-20  636  6.000000 weeks  6 weeks
# 2017-04-06  697  8.428571 weeks  8 weeks
# 2017-04-20  566 10.428571 weeks 10 weeks
# 2017-05-05  234 12.571429 weeks 12 weeks
```